# What happens when you bump into a black hole while space traveling (not at/through event horizon)?

Tags: black-holes, space

Let's assume a galaxy has super massive black hole in it's center. We can't see what's inside the black hole because light cannot escape from it.

In simple terms, black hole is a hole in the space and also assume that this black hole goes down all the way somewhere, like a straw/pipe that we cannot see.

So now imagine a a spaceship is traveling exactly beneath the supermassive blackhole (but far away from event horizon where the blackhole can't pull it inside). And now what happens if the spaceship hits the blackhole straw/pipe?

Just trying to understand is there any science that we can use to see where this blackhole straw/pipe goes to from outside. Or what happens if a spaceship or a planet hits this pipe?

Comment: In other way, let's just assume 2 galaxies are connected by a black hole in their center (like 2 discs connected by a pipe) and what happens if you hit the (wormhole)pipe when you are traveling in between these discs?

Comment: What do you mean "beneath"? In space, there isn't any "down." A black hole has spherical symmetry.

Comment: So, light can't travel through space from one side to other side like a needle in a cloth? And light only can travel on space?

Answer (score 1):

In our 3D space, the event horizon completely surrounds the black hole.   There is no "pipe" or structure that you can reach without entering the event horizion (at least not without getting into even more exotic species of black holes).

There is no structure that connects two distant black holes other than their gravitational pull.

Comment: Ok, ignore the concept of a black hole connecting 2 galaxies. What happens when you hit a wormhole in the middle from outside?

Comment: If wormholes exist (and we have no evidence they do), they exist outside our 3D space.   We couldn't reach one any more than you can reach a subway train by walking on the surface of the earth.

Comment: @TheGuest - There *is no* "middle from the outside" in a wormhole. There is *no way* to get to the "funnel" or the "straw/pipe" from the "outside" (that is, without entering the wormhole).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't hit the event horizon, it will depend on just how fast you are going. The closer you come, the faster you have to be going to avoid being sucked into the horizon and thus unable to escape and then crushed at the core. If you're going fast enough, you will effectively "slingshot" around the black hole just like around a planet.

Interestingly, given "cruising the Galaxy" would require a speed close to $c$, you could actually get quite close to the horizon without being pulled in, and if you did so, some rather weird things would happen. The nonlinearity of gravitational effects there would mean that instead of a simple Newtonian-like hyperbolic trajectory, you might be able to run a few orbits around the hole before escaping.

(This is also why I mentioned about being "sucked in" at all; in Newtonian gravity, there isn't really "sucking", but in the nonlinear regime of Einsteinian GR, there kind of is, in that a speed and angle of attack that in NG would send you into the clear, would actually end up having you indeed spiral inward.)

I don't know what you mean by a "straw/pipe". The black hole attracts things toward it from all directions, mostly (but not perfectly, due to angular momentum) uniformly. I suspect you're thinking of that "rubber sheet" diagram, where the black hole looks like a "funnel". That diagram is misleading or, if you like, *you are within* the rubber sheet; the external space is of empirically-unassessable (so far) reality.

(Even then, it's still misleading. That funnel has negative curvature; space around a black hole has a *positive* curvature!)

Comment: I suspect you're thinking of that "rubber sheet" diagram, where the black hole looks like a "funnel" - Yes, exactly. This is what I was asking that what happens if you hit the funnel from outside because you can't see the funnel.

Comment: @The Guest: You can't, because that "funnel" _is_ the space you are travelling in in your spaceship, i.e. it is _made of_ the space of our Universe. The "outside", _if_ it existed, would be "hyperspace"; i.e. space _outside_ our Universe's space. To put it another way, your ship is fully within the surface of the sheet.